# based on a condition i want to separate the column and add the value in different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, python-2.7

This code will give one column which is having lists

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,None],[1,2],[2,4],[None],[1,2,None]],'b':[1,2,3,5,6]})
print df
OutPut - 
               a  b
  0     [1, None]  1
  1        [1, 2]  2
  2        [2, 4]  3
  3        [None]  5
  4  [1, 2, None]  6
```

where my expectation is that if list contains None then those list i want to put in a different Dataframe.
and my first DataFrame result should

```
        a    b
   0  [1, 2] 2
   1  [2, 4] 3
```

Second DataFrame result should

```
        a        b
 0     [1, None] 1
 1        [None] 4
 2  [1, None, 2] 5
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
mask = pd.Series([None in x for x in df['a']])

# or more pandas-like style
# mask = df['a'].explode().isna().any(level=0)

# second part
df[mask]

$ first part
df[~mask]
```